# Axios API call returning Promise object instead of result?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Before I start, let me say that I'm new to Javascript and very new to axios API calls, so I'm probably making a rookie mistake...

I have this function `getObjects()` that's meant to map over an array and return the data from an Axios API call. The API call and map function are both working, but I'm getting a Promise object instead of the data I'm trying to get.

I figure this is because the data is returned before there's enough time to actually get it, but not sure how to fix? I tried a `.setTimeout()`, but that didn't seem to work.

```
  getObjects() {
    let newsItems = this.state.arrayofids.map((index) => {
      let resultOfIndex = axios.get(`https:\/\/hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${index}.json`).then((res) => {
          let data = res.data;
          //console.log(data.by); // this prints the correct byline, but
                              // all the bylines are printed after
                              // the console.log below...
          if (!data.hasOwnProperty('text')) return data;
        }); /// end of axios request
  return resultOfIndex;
    }); /// end of map
    /// ideally this would end in an array of response objects but instead i'm getting an array of promises...
    console.log(newsItems);
  }
```

(The extra escape characters are for my text editor's benefit.)

[Here's a link to a codepen with the issue](http://codepen.io/jlr7245/pen/apOjbM) - open up the console to see the problem. It's a React project but I don't think any of the React stuff is the issue. ***EDIT:** Codepen is link to working solution using `axios.all` as suggested below*

Thanks!

**EDIT: Here is my working solution.**

```
getObjects() {
  let axiosArr = [];
  axios.all(this.state.arrayofids.map((id) => {
      return axios.get(`https:\/\/hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json`)
    })).then((res) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.state.arrayofids.length; i++) {
        axiosArr.push(<li key={i} data-url={res[i].data.url} onClick={(e) => this.displayTheNews(e)}>{res[i].data.title}</li>);
      }
      if (axiosArr.length == this.state.arrayofids.length) {
        this.setState({arrayofdata: axiosArr});
        console.log('state is set!');
      }
    })
 }
```

Comment: Not an expert, but I've used it for a little while. I'm pretty sure that it only returns promises as there's a `axios.all` function. You will have to work out the logic inside the then, which I suggest using `this.setState` or redux equivalent. You actually might want to look at `axios.all` instead of doing this mapping.

Comment: @A.Lau Oh, great, this definitely put me on the right path. Thanks so much.

Comment: I'll put it as answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`axios.all` function should be more appropriate to your current scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Your `console.log` is executing immediately, rather than waiting for the requests to finish, because they are not synchronous. You have to wait for all the responses before you `console.log`.

**OPTION 1** (the hard way):
replace your `console.log` with

```
newsItems.forEach((promise, index) => {
  promise.then((object)=>{
    newsItems[index] = object
    if (index+1 == newsItems.length) {
      console.log(newsItems)
    }
  })
})
```

**OPTION 2** (the better way):
using `axios.all`

```
  getObjects() {
    axios.all(this.state.arrayofids.map((id) => {
      return axios.get(`https:\/\/hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json`)
    })).then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

by the way, I would definitely reccommend changing

```
this.state.arrayofids.map((index) => {
      let resultOfIndex = axios.get(`https:\/\/hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${index}.json`)...
```

to be called `id` instead of `index`